# setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) How to cancel selection?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which uses:

```
setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
```

So when the user clicks on a list item it is displayed as selected. This works fine and automatically selects the item.

Note: The standard action when the user clicks on a list item is that it updates some content in another fragment.

But there are some list items in the list which I do not want selected. Instead of updating content I show a dialog box. The trouble is, when the user has got rid of the dialog box, the item is still marked as selected, which I don't want. In fact I don't want it to be selected at all, and keep the previously selected list item selected.

Is there any way to programmatically select a list item (so you can choose whether to set it selected, or not), and at the same time use the CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE because this ensures that only 1 item in the list is currently selected ?

Comment: so you're saying you want to select an item on the list, then click another item on the list and not change which item is selected?

Answer (score 6):

Look at this code:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            mListView.setItemChecked(position, false);
        }
    }
});
```

It unselects list item, if chosen first item. Also you can save last correct position

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            mListView.setItemChecked(mLastCorrectPosition, true);
        }
        else {
            mLastCorrectPosition = position;
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Full activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private String[] mData = new String[] { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "aaa" };
    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mLastCorrectPosition = -1;
    private int mButtonPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mData);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0));

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                if (position == mButtonPosition) {
                    if (mLastCorrectPosition != -1) {
                        mListView.setItemChecked(mLastCorrectPosition, true);
                    }
                    else {
                        mListView.setItemChecked(mButtonPosition, false);
                    }
                    // here show dialog
                }
                else {
                    mLastCorrectPosition = position;
                    // here refresh fragment
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```